# Can I add a new reference to my accepted paper?

Tags: publications, citations, doi

My paper was accepted and the journal asked me for corrections before publication. After corrections they will give it a doi number. Can I add a new reference at this stage or is it a risk?

Answer (score 4):

I doubt that it is more than a tiny risk unless it introduces something fundamentally new or different to the paper.

Ask yourself whether it is really needed. If so, then add it but also give the editor a note that you have done so.

I think the main risk would be for a short delay.